# Make small caps work with erewhon and mathdesign

Tags: fonts

I use the package `erewhon` for Utopia and `mathdesign` for the accompanying math typeface. If I use `mathdesign`, though, `\textsc` and `\scshape` don't work anymore: the document compiles smoothly ignoring those commands. How can I make them work with both packages?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\begin{document}
\scshape
Be small caps!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mathdesign` package redefines `\scdefault` to be `fsc` for its own font management, that you want to avoid, since you just need the math fonts. Revert it to the standard.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{erewhon}

\renewcommand{\scdefault}{sc}

\begin{document}
\scshape
Be small caps!
\end{document}
```

[image]

You should consider using `\usepackage{fourier}`, instead of `\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}`.

Comment: Excusez moi but, why `fourier`?

Comment: @ArchStanton They are math fonts specifically crafted to accompany Utopia.

Comment: As of 2020, `erewhon` (as well as `XCharter` and `garamondx`) load `fontaxes`, which as a side-effect patches up the bugs created by `mathdesign`.